# Conditional rendering shows both components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components that I'm rendering based on the condition of a state, but I'm running into a problem where the wrong component is displayed a split second before the right component is displayed.

Fetching data async:

```
  const [test, setTest] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState();
  const [error, setError] = useState(); 

  const fetchData = async () => {
    console.log("running");
    setLoading(true);
    setError(false);
    try {
      const result = await axios(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/props.selectedId" // Is dynamic and changes on user click
      );
      setTest(result.data);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response.status == 404) {
        setError(error);
        setTest(null);
      }
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };
```

Rendering:

```
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {!loading && !error && test? (
        <div>
          <Card className={classes.card}>
            <CardContent>
              <Title>Adattributes</Title>
              <Typography variant="h6" component="h1">
                name
              </Typography>
              <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                  <Typography variant="subtitle2" component="h1">
                    address
                  </Typography>
                  {test.title}
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions>
              <Component1
                value={test}
                setTest={setTest}
              />
            </CardActions>
          </Card>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <Component2 setTest={setTest} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
});
```

Am I doing something wrong with the conditional rendering? Or do it have something to do with fetching async?

Comment: what dou you mean by wrong component? also set state in an async function is not batched so every setState will trigger a rerender, but since your setLoading(false) is last I would say you wont see the result before (if I am seeing it correctly loading and error both render Component2)

Comment: I had the same issue I solve it by using CSS display block and none,  use CSS display property to show and hide component based on state

Answer (score 0):

The initial state of your `test` state is falsy. This, plus operator precedence can lead to wrong errors. See http://www-lia.deis.unibo.it/materiale/JS/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence.html.

Probably what you want to so is:

```
(!loading && !error && test) ? ... : ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first line you use *useState* hook without initial state, so your state become *undefined* (remember that *undefined* is falsy value).

```
const [test, setTest] = useState();
```

Either you should set initial state for *test*, or change your condition for rendering component.